# PHP - Destroying Sessions properly on un-submitted form pages?

Tags: php, session

If I have a php contact form with session_start() at the top, I know this creates a session. But what if the user doesn't fill out the form and instead navigates to a different page?

Do I still need to use session_destroy since I only want a session created when a user submits a php form via my contact page?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** For a better idea on my form without posting lengthy code.

contact-form.html

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $fname = isset($_SESSION['fname'] ) ? $_SESSION['fname'] : NULL ; ?>
<form method="post" action="http://www.mysite.com/form-process.php">
  <input value="<?php echo $fname ?>" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" />
</form>
```

form-process.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$user = "John" ;
session_write_close(); 
if ($_SESSION['fname'] != $user) {
   header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/contact-form.html');
} 
else {
  $_SESSION = array();
  session_destroy();
  header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/thankyou.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: How large is your application? The cost of creating a session is minimal so I would say that you 99/100 dont need to care about this.

Comment: You can check for if the POST variables are submitted each time (maybe with a hidden-field identifier to differentiate it from other forms). If they don't exist, just destroy the session.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The application is just two pages :). contact-form.php and process-form.php with session_start() only on those two pages within the website. I believe the answers below, address my concern though :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want a session created when the user submits certain form, just do it as you describe. It's not mandatory to put `session_start()` on every page of the site and it doesn't need to be the first line in the file (it just needs to be able to generate a cookie, thus it needs to be before any *output*).

```
// contact-form.php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    session_start();
    // ...
}
```

The stateless nature of HTTP makes it impossible to actively remove a session if the user hasn't completed certain task. But if you don't load session on other parts of the site, the session file will be removed on next garbage collection after its expiration time, even if the user is still browsing your site. Other than that, a session is just a tiny text file lying harmlessly on a temporary directory.

Comment: Never thought of doing it that way. Especially since multiple people cautioned that absolutely no space can be before the session_start(). Quick question though, my contact-form.php files sends the post to a form-process.php file to process the input of the contact form. In this scenario your code won't work right? Because the POST goes to another page, thus the contact-form.php file doesn't reload to initiate that IF statement for the session.

Comment: No space can be **sent to the browser**—that's a particular case of "no output before session_start()". If you understand how cookies work you'll realise that there's nothing wrong if you e.g. indent the session_start() line. And my code can be adapted to your scenario if you understand what it does—it's not intended for blind copy+paste.

Comment: I've accepted your response as the answer as it was more detailed and included the code suggestion. I understand what your code is doing, but if my form-process.php script sends the user to the contact-us.php form to correct entered information, then I am not sure how that would work. Would I put an IF statement to only use session_start() if a session exists or something like that?

Comment: A contact form should use POST rather than GET. In your scenario, how are you transmitting the filled in info back to the form? It's all easier if code from `form-process.php` goes on top of `contact-us.php`.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my response. I have updated my main post with a snippet to basically show how my form functions and returns to the form page. Keep in mind, I may have over thought this and went about it all wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The overhead of creating a session is miniscule, there's no real reason you'd need to `session_destroy()` though you could put the `session_start()` in the block that detects post rather than at the top of the script if you only want to use the session when the user posts.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Oshawott . It was a hard choice but I accepted the other answer as it provided a bit more detail.